# PostgreSQL - How to prevent duplicate inserts in a competitive slot taking contest

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, locking

I don't know how to phrase my question right. But to provide further details about the problem I am trying to solve, let me describe my application. Suppose I am trying to implement a queue reservation application, and I maintain the number of slots in a table roughly.

```
id | appointment | slots_available | slots_total
---------------------------------------------------
1  | apt 1       |      30         |     30
2  | apt 2       |      1          |     5
.. | ..          |      ..         |     ..
```

So, in a competitive scenario, assuming that everything works in the application side of things. A scenario can happen in the application where :

```
user 1 -> reserves apt 2 -> [validate if slot exists] -> update slot_available to 0 -> reserve (insert a record)
user 2 -> reserves ap2 2 -> validate if slot exists -> [update slot_available to 0] -> reserve (insert a record)
```

What if user 1 and 2 happens to find a **slot available for apt2 at the same time** in the user interface? (Of course I would validate first if there is one slot, but they would see the same value in the UI if not one of them has clicked yet). Then the two submits a reservation at the same time.

Now what if user 1 validates that there is a slot that is available, even though user 2 has already taken it though the update operation is not yet done? Then **there will be two inserts**.

At any case, how do I ensure that only one of them gets the reservation at **database level**? I'm sure this is a common scenario, but I have no idea yet on how to implement something like this. A suggestion to remodel would also be acceptable as long as it solves the scenario.

Comment: `insert on conflict do update`

Comment: i believe insert on conflict is like when you're checking conflict inserts in the same table.. what if i dont really have conflict with the "reservation" table at all.. but i want to use the "slots" table as reference on whether or not the insert on the "reservation" table is allowed or not.